# Passing C variable to C++ function

Tags: c++, c

I have an android project with OpenSL ES and need to do some cleaning up.

One of the things I want to do is separate some logic from one file.

The file has the following variable defined:

```
static SLObjectItf engineObject = NULL;
```

This is a C variable as we access it like so:

```
(*engineObject)->Realize(engineObject, SL_BOOLEAN_FALSE);
```

I am trying to pass it off to another C++ class like so:

```
audioBuffer->Create(&engineObject);
```

This is how you would normally pass a pointer to `SLObjectItf` but it's a C variable so there is some different behaviour here.

This seems like a fairly straightforward task, here is the recieving function:

```
AudioBuffer::Create(SLObjectItf* engineEngine) 
{
    // ....
    (*engineEngine)->CreateAudioPlayer(engineEngine, &bqPlayerObject, &audioSrc, &audioSnk,
            3, ids, req);
}
```

And the error is:

```
request for member 'CreateAudioPlayer' in '* * engineEngine', which is of pointer type 'const SLEngineItf_* const' (maybe you meant to use '->' ?)
```

How do I pass a C variable into a C++ function and use it there?

Comment: What is `SLObjectItf`? And do you really need that many pointer indirections?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg It's a struct. Here is the header file: https://www.khronos.org/registry/sles/api/1.0/OpenSLES.h

Comment: did you try (engineEngine)->....

Comment: Looks like `engineObject` is pointer to structure, so you don't need to pass pointer to it in `audioBuffer->Create(&engineObject);`. If you do `engineEngine` is `pointer to pointer` so do `(*(*engineEngine))->CreateAudioPlayer(...)`

Comment: it seems like `SLObjectItf` is a pointer to a pointer to struct. `(*engineEngine)` first indirection; `->func()` second indirection. so your function needs more indirection.

Comment: If `engineObject` is really a C variable, then what is `Realize` ? Because `(*engineObject)->Realize(...)` looks like a C++ method call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When looking at the header file, I see that `SLObjectItf` is defined as

```
typedef const struct SLObjectItf_ * const * SLObjectItf;
```

That means it's a pointer to pointer to a structure. When you pass a pointer to the `SLObjectItf` variable you pass a pointer to pointer to pointer to the structure, so `*engineEngine` is the pointer to pointer to structure. You need another dereference operator, or simply not pass it as a pointer.

Comment: Right, makes sense. I just had to change `Create(SLEngineItf* engineEngine)` to `Create(SLEngineItf engineEngine)` and pass `engineEngine` instead of `&engineEngine`

Answer (score 0):

'engineEngine' is passed as a pointer, try

```
engineEngine->CreateAudioPlayer(......
```

or

```
(*engineEngine).CreateAudioPlayer(.....
```